# Can I find all the Tetra Master cards in Disc 4?

Tags: final-fantasy-9

Simply as that, I just want to know if it is possible to find all the cards in the last disc or if I will miss some. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can find every card in Disc 4 execpt the [Namingway](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Namingway#Final_Fantasy_IX), which is present only in Disc 3:

- Got from Kuja's room in **Desert Palace** (near the teleporter, only after Eiko has been kidnapped)
- Win from Mario during **Treno's card tournament**. When the player is in control of Vivi, they are given the option of "going home", or staying in Treno. Choosing the latter will give Zidane a different opponent in the card tournament's second round, who holds the Namingway card.

Anyway, you can check the [complete card list and relative location](https://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/197338-final-fantasy-ix/faqs/24067). Only that card seems to be unavailable out of Disc 4.